# Why does BigDecimal return this value after rounding half up?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

Why does `BigDecimal` return this value after rounding half up instead of the expected value, and how can I reach this?

```
// EXPECTED 0.45
// RETURNS 0.45
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("0.45"))
                             .setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString());

// EXPECTED 0.45
// RETURNS 0.45
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("0.445"))
                             .setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString());

// EXPECTED 0.45
// RETURNS 0.44
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("0.4445"))
                             .setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toPlainString());
```

Comment: round(0.4445) = 0.44 is ok. Why 0.4445 should become 0.45?

Comment: 0.44 is closer to 0.4445 than 0.45 would be.

Comment: Rounding operations are done on the first discarded fraction, not on every discarded fraction recursivly. I guess you expected the rounding to go 0.4445->0.445->0.45. But as others have pointed out already this would actually give you horrible results.

Comment: I am looking for a way to get the expected result. I thought that 0.4445 would set the third 4 to a 5 and that would set the second 4 to a 5? Is there a rounding method for this?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Is there a way around? Or can i not use the BigDecimal variable for this?

Comment: You are not following the standard "number roles" :) so you need to write your own method :)

Comment: There is no inbuilt rounding mode that does what you want it to do. What you want to do is mathematically incorrect (or at least not how it is usually done). I would recommend you think about if you really want to round the way you described in the question or if rounding the way it is usually done everywhere else isn't the better solution..

Comment: I think you need to go back a level, and ask about whatever it is that is inspiring you to want this weird and unnecessarily inaccurate rounding mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the literal question

> Why does BigDecimal return this value after rounding half up instead
>   of the expected value and how can i reach this?

applied to 0.4445 rounding to 0.44 rather than "expected" 0.45.

[BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) is defined as

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both
>   neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.

The scale factor two neighbors are 0.44 and 0.45. The absolute difference between 0.4445 and 0.44 is 0.0045. The absolute difference between 0.4445 and 0.45 is 0.0055. The neighbors are not equidistant and 0.44 is the nearest neighbor.

If you really, really want a weird and unnecessarily inaccurate rounding mode, use BigDecimal's toString method to get the full String representation. You can then mangle it any way you like using String operations.

Comment: Using strings is one possiblity. Or (s)he could use `setScale()` repeatedly, starting high and decreasing the scale until it reaches the target scale. That would give `0.4445 -> 0.445 -> 0.45`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, that would work for this particular case. However, the next time the OP wants to force an incorrect double to print as a target value, a different manipulation may be needed. The String approach is more flexible.

Comment: Well yes, of course it is never a good idea to initialize a BigDecimal with a double that was initialized with a string. But ISTM that the same manipulation would be needed.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis There are double-related calculations that are best done in BigDecimal, regardless of where the value of the double came from.